# Unable to install spacy with Anaconda

Tags: python, nlp, anaconda, spacy

The error that my pycharm shows me is this:

Executed command:

> **C:\Users\Felipe\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe install -p C:/Users/Felipe/Anaconda3/envs/NLP spacy -y**

Error ocurred:

> **UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other**:

Command output:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...working... 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed
Building graph of deps:   0%|          | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Examining python=3.8:   0%|          | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]  
Examining spacy:  33%|###3      | 1/3 [00:00<00:00, 21.35it/s]
Examining @/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0:  67%|######6   | 2/3 [00:01<00:00,  1.95it/s]
Examining @/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0: 100%|##########| 3/3 [00:01<00:00,  2.92it/s]
                                                                                 
Determining conflicts:   0%|          | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Examining conflict for python spacy:   0%|          | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Examining conflict for __cuda:  33%|###3      | 1/3 [00:00<00:00,  5.01it/s]
Examining conflict for __cuda:  67%|######6   | 2/3 [00:00<00:00, 10.02it/s]
                                                                            
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:
  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0
  - feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0
Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.0
```

I realy need to get trouth this to keep studing!

Answer (score 1):

To install the most recent version of spacy with conda (which includes builds for python 3.8), install spacy from the `conda-forge` channel with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```